# Close date range calendar component after choosing two dates

Tags: angular, calendar, frontend, primeng, date-range

PrimeNg delivers really good Calendar component which works really fine, but is there a way to close it after choosing 2 dates?

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="rangeDates" 
            selectionMode="range"
            [readonlyInput]="true"></p-calendar>
```

In [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar)  I noticed two interesting things as:
- Event `onSelect`, unfortunately it would've work on normal calendar, where we do one press (here we need to press twice)
- Property: `hideOnDateTimeSelect`, but it seems like it isnt what I'm looking for, because it doesn't work either.

I think i could've do something like:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="rangeDates" 
            selectionMode="range"
            [readonlyInput]="true"
            (onSelect)="onSelect()"></p-calendar>

private dateSelected() {
    if (this.rangeDates[0] !== null && this.rangeDates[1] !== null) {
    //really dont know how to do "close" right now.
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know if is there any way to select always two dates. I am able to select only one, but I don't want this.

Comment: @J.Abel I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but for sure it's possible. For instance, u can try to use one of the events e.g. `onClose`, and then set up some custom behavior if selected dates contain only 1 date (throw exception, set up some warning, clean field or copy date so you will get date range from same day). Also, there is a built-in calendar property called `focusTrap` and maybe that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The below worked for me:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="rangeDates" 
    selectionMode="range" #calendar
    [readonlyInput]="true"
    (onSelect)="onSelect()"></p-calendar>

@ViewChild('calendar', undefined) private calendar: any;
private onSelect(){
  if (this.rangeDates[1]) { // If second date is selected
    this.calendar.overlayVisible=false;
}
 }
```

I know it is pretty late to answer your question, but still answered it for people like me who are tryin to find an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

this.datePicker.hideOverlay();

use hideOverlay() method to close date range picker pop up after selection of from and to date (use with viewchild)